# Federation enabled on-premises Skype for Business support in Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

I have a bot that is successfully running on localhost and also with ngrok and webchat.

I know that Skype for business channel can only be enabled for Skype for business online and office 365 online.

Now I want to now, can federation enabled on-premises Skype for business be integrated with Microsoft bot.

Note: Federation enabled on premise Skype for business is on a virtual setup and behind a company firewall.

I am confused as I can be found by the employees of other companies who also use Skype for Business then should not on-premises Skype be able to connect to Microsoft Bot Connector.

Comment: As it says in the documentation, only SfB Online is supported.

Answer (score 1):

**Supported Skype for Business versions:**
The Skype for Business Bot Framework channel is currently supported for Skype for Business Online and Skype for Business Hybrid environments only.

*Note: Skype for Business Server 2015 is currently not a supported Microsoft Bot Framework channel.*

**Skype for Business Hybrid environment support details:**
Skype for Business bots can be connected to Skype for Business Server users if Hybrid connectivity has been deployed in the environment. For more information about hybrid connectivity and bot setup, see Skype for Business Bot - Hybrid environment support.

For more information on configuring the Skype for Business channel in Microsoft Bot Framework, check out:

- Skype for Business docs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview
- Bot Framework SfB channel guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness